# How to add Face Id Authentication in Xamarin forms for the Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm looking for the solution in Xamarin forms to implement Face Id authentication. If the user has enabled Face Id on their mobile, there will be a prompt to scan their face for authentication. I have tried a lot but not found any solution.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm mistaken Android devices don't have the hardware to do this. Sure, you could use the camera and sprinkle AI over it to determine if there is a face in the picture and if the eyes are looking at the screen, but that will be a big undertaking.

iOS has Face ID which has all of this built-in, not just in it's software, but also in their hardware with a variety of sensors to support this scenario.

If you want to look into making fingerprint and Face ID usage easier, check out the [Xamarin Biometrics plugin](https://github.com/smstuebe/xamarin-fingerprint).

Comment: When it comes to Android's vast OEM devices, some have "face id", some do not. Some are starting to use ToF sensors on the "selfie side", most are still just using the 2D selfie cam w/o ToF data. i.e. Using the Android Biometric API on some Samsung models (s20+ include Sony's ToF sensor, they also announced they own inhouse developed ToF sensor) will invoke their face unlock feature vs. the fingerprint sensor, this is configured within the global settings. As a developer, just use the Biometric API and it will do pin, fingerprint, face, etc... based upon the OEM's hardware  and user settings